# Code blocks are not supported in this context.When Binding Html Table With dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i have html datatable and dataset .i want to bind the dataset to html table.And my datarow count is 25  and it throws error "Code blocks are not supported in this context.".Pls help me to rectify the issue.

```
 public string getWhileLoopData()
{
 string htmlStr = "";
  MastersClient objIndent = new MastersClient();
                DataSet ds = objIndent.GetIndent(hidIndentID.Value);

                DataRow[] drIndentID = ds.Tables[0].Select("IndentID =" + hidIndentID.Value);

                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    txtQty.Value = drIndentID[i]["RecommentedQuantity"].ToString();
                    string Qty=txtQty.Value ;
                    string strProductID = drIndentID[i]["ProductID"].ToString();
                    ddlProduct.Text = strProductID;
                    txtDate.Text = drIndentID[i]["ProductRequiredDate"].ToString();
                    string date= txtDate.Text;
                    htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + Qty + "</td><td>" + strProductID + "</td><td>" + date + "</td></tr>"; 
                }


        return htmlStr;
}





<table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1" runat="server">
        <tr <%Response.Write(getWhileLoopData())%>>
            <td><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk" runat="server"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="txtQty" runat="server"/></td>
            <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server"  Style="width: 100%; height:23px" ></asp:DropDownList>  


            </td>
           <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" Style="text-align: left" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, false);"
                                                        onblur="DateValidation(this)" onkeyup="ValidateDate(this, event.keyCode)" onkeydown="return DateFormat(this, event.keyCode)"
                                                        Height="20px" runat="server" Width="80px"> </asp:TextBox>


           </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Instead of using `Response.Write()`, use a Repeater or GridView and bind to the data.

Comment: @mason where to place response write?

Comment: I said to get rid of `Response.Write()` and to use a server side control instead. It makes more sense in this situation.

Comment: @mason Is there any other way to do without using repeater or gridview

Comment: Of course there is. But why *not* use Repeater or GridView? Do you not understand them? Is there some hidden requirement you haven't described?

Comment: @mason i am using static method so i am passing the textbox value and dropdown values to webmethod so i move to this

Comment: You haven't shown any static methods. And still, that doesn't say why you're not using Repeater or GridView and you're stuck on this idea of using `Response.Write`.

Answer (score 0):

This situation begs for a GridView or Repeater. Here's an abbreviate view of what the repeater might look like:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="ProductRepeater">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chk" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" id="txtQty" Text='<%#: Eval("RecommentedQuantity") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Then bind your data on page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        MastersClient objIndent = new MastersClient();
        DataSet ds = objIndent.GetIndent(hidIndentID.Value);
        ProductRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].Select("IndentID =" + hidIndentID.Value);
        ProductRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

script tags `<% %>` should be placed inside a asp placeholder.

Add all your `<%%>` code inside `<asp:PlaceHolder>your code with <%><%> here </asp:PlaceHolder>`

CODE:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhTable" runat="server">
<table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1" runat="server">
        <tr <%Response.Write(getWhileLoopData())%>>
            <td><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk" runat="server"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="txtQty" runat="server"/></td>
            <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server"  Style="width: 100%; height:23px" ></asp:DropDownList>  


            </td>
           <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" Style="text-align: left" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, false);"
                                                        onblur="DateValidation(this)" onkeyup="ValidateDate(this, event.keyCode)" onkeydown="return DateFormat(this, event.keyCode)"
                                                        Height="20px" runat="server" Width="80px"> </asp:TextBox>


           </td>
        </tr>

    </table>   
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: try removing `runat="server"` for your `<table></table>`

Comment: If i remove runat="server"  it throws object reference error'